# multiple node reference formatted in drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

In my website, I have a section for documents. Those documents are available in different languages.
When I show those documents, I want to group them to have an input like that :

Document-001 [ENGLISH] [DUTCH] [CHINESE] [FRENCH]

... and when we click on "english" , it download the english version.

How can I do ?

Right now, I have a CCK named "documents" where I put files and description. I'm trying to use them to show it like the example above but I didn't found the way to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the "Field collections" Module to set "Document" and "Language" fields.

With that implementaion, in every node, I can attach multiple documents and languages.